# Send TCP packets with Curl

Tags: networking, batch, cmd.exe, tcp, curl

Background :

I want to have computers communicate to each other so I used to use Dropbox for syncing them. I used one program to echo information in a text file, then the other computer would have an "if this then that" program. However, this took a long time to sync and I could not use the same method with a phone.

The Point :

I want to use curl to send text, images, audio clips, etc. (text for now). I used in batch `curl 192.168.0.170:59403`. That would work but on the receiving end it would say `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.0.170:59403\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.53.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n` I want that to be text. Any Ideas?

Comment: `curl` is a HTTP client and what you see is a HTTP request.

Comment: Use netcat.  Netcat gives you a nice raw TCP connect that you can do anything you like with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can send raw text with curl to any host:port as netcat would do, using the telnet protocol:

```
curl telnet://192.168.0.170:59403 <<< someText
```

Answer (score 1):

In BASH you can send with `cat file > /dev/tcp/address/port`.